# How to hide Actionbar and not to hide statusbar(titlebar)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

Check the below image I need same things in my app.
[image]
I wanted to hide just actionbar not statusbar(titlebar). I use below code where both actionbar and statusbar hide.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you don't have a toolbar/actionbar in this activity i guess.

Comment: I think you are confused about the `status bar` and `action bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using this code, you can hide `actionbar` and `statubar` will remain in design.

Just add this in your style.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NooActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

add below code in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NooActionBar" />
```